# Strange behaviour with strings and arrays

Tags: arrays, string, powershell

Here I assign the value of an array to a variable, I then alter the variable, the array changes also.

```powershell
$TestArray = @{ "ValueA" = "A" ; "ValueB" = "B" ; "Number" = "" }
$TestNumbers = 1..10

foreach ($number in $testnumbers) {

    $results = $TestArray
    $results.Number = $number
    Write-Host $TestArray.Number

}
```

I thought that `$results = $TestArray` would take a copy of `$TestArray` but this test shows that modifying `$results` also changes the corresponding value in `$TestArray`

Can anyone help me understand this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing:

```powershell
$results = $TestArray
```

will make `$results` a *reference* to the same object referred to by `TestArray`. So, if you change one, the other will also be affected because they are the same object.

---

To instead make `$results` a *copy* of `$TestArray`, you can use its [`Clone` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.clone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```powershell
$results = $TestArray.Clone()
```

---

Also, just for the record, `$TestArray` is not actually an array.  It is a [hashtable](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-hash-tables.html) (also called a hashmap) where keys are paired with values.  An array would be something like:

```powershell
$TestArray = (1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Thanks, I am really surprised that I have only just noticed this behaviour.
It makes sense.
I am wondering is the _reference_ behaviour applicable to all strings  arrays hashtables and objects?

Comment: It depends on if the object in question can be mutated or not.  If it is something like a hashtable, then yes, because you can add/remove items from it.  If it is an immutable object such as a string, then no because strings cannot be changed (all operations on them produce new objects instead of modifying the old ones).  Here is an explanation on the difference between mutable objects and immutable ones: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object.